# How to append to a partitioned table in BigQuery with client libraries (Python)?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have searched on the web extensively and also read the relevant API references and BQ guide posts including [this one](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-table-data#append-overwrite), but nothing seems to be directly relevant.

The table of interest is an ingestion-time partitioned table. I have created an initial table and now need to append more data. I tried to run the code below:

```
job_config = bq.LoadJobConfig(source_format=bq.SourceFormat.CSV, skip_leading_row=1, write_disposition='WRITE_APPEND')

with open(file_path, 'rb') as source_file:
    job = client.load_table_from_file(source_file, table_id, job_config=job_config)
```

But, it doesn't work, even though there is no error raised. Some guide post mentioned adding a partition decorator for the destination table, so I added a timestamp at the end of table_id, it still doesn't work.

Please help make appending possible!!

P.S.:
I don't want to have date-sharded tables instead, as it is not good practice in comparison.

Answer (score 1):

To check if the table is indeed ingestion-time partitioned just click on it and select "Details":
[image]

Since your table as partitioned by day, then the `_PARTITIONTIME` will be the same for all rows inserted during the same day. Try inserting new rows tomorrow.

Comment: Thanks, Sergey. 1. I have the same details shown as in your screenshot, but I wonder if it "time-unit column-partitioned" tables will have the same details listed. 2. Say it is ingestion-time partitioned table already, I have been trying to append on different days, but as stated in the question, the code didn't work... And that is the biggest mystery.

Comment: Oh, sorry then. For "time-unit column-partitioned" tables "Partitioned on field" contains column name.

Comment: No worries. Thank you all the same.

Answer (score 0):

```py
from google.cloud import bigquery

items = [
   (1, 'foo'),
   (2, 'bar')
]

# Create a new Google BigQuery client using Google Cloud Platform project
# defaults.
client = bigquery.Client()

# Get a reference to a dataset
dataset_id = "natality_regression"
dataset = bigquery.dataset(dataset_id)

# Get table
table_ref = dataset.table("regression_input$20210423")
table = client.get_table(table_ref)
errors = client.insert_rows(table, items)
```

The sdk uses the API, so as this is [exposed in the API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables), the answer is to append a `$` and a date (say, `20210423`) to the table name in the selector.